# SPARQL - adding {} gives no answer

Tags: sparql

I have a SPARQL query which gives (with suitable prefix) an answer; it contains a spurious `{`} which I added to prepare for UNION .

```
FROM <http://gerastree.at/t3>    
where  {
        ?tok a nlp:Token . 
        { ?tok nlp:pos ?cats .
          filter   (strstarts(str(?cats),"V")) .}

}   limit 10
```

if a change the parenthesis like:

```
FROM <http://gerastree.at/t3>    # nt files Partial
where  {
        ?tok a nlp:Token . 
        ?tok nlp:pos ?cats .
        { filter   (strstarts(str(?cats),"V")) .}

}   limit 10
```

The answer is empty. It seems that the binding of ?cats is not available inside the parenthesis?

Comment: That's correct. In the second query it evaluates to `join
          (bgp
            (triple ?tok rdf:type nlp:Token)
            (triple ?tok nlp:pos ?cats)
          )
          (filter (strstarts (str ?cats) "V")
            (table unit)))`, i.e. you have a filter on an empty table

Comment: To understand it better, keep in mind the SPARQL evaluation is done bottom-up, with inner `{ }` brackets  you build subgroups. The filter variable is not in scope.

Comment: missing information: what does `bgp` mean? - I assumed that the evaluation is row-by-row top-to-bottom; does a subgroup evaluate first, i.e. the `?tok a nlp::Token:` is done last?

Comment: `bgp` -> [basic graph pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#BasicGraphPatterns)  no, evaluation is down bottom-up, subgroups (and sub-queryies) will be evaluated first. For the other two triple patterns, the order of evaluation doesn't matter. there will just be a join in the end between the two triple patterns and the subgroup (which is evaluated to an empty mapping) - that'S why the join will be empty and the query doesn't return anything.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification.